# Delete rows from SQL server bases on content in dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have an inventory table in a SQL Server called `dbo.inventory` which contains `Year`, `Month`, `Material` and `Stock_quantity`. I receive a new inventory count as csv file each day and need to load this into the `dbo.inventory` table. I do however need to delete records in the database if `Year` and `Month` from the csv file already exits in the database in order to avoid loading multiple inventory counts for the same month.

In SQL I would do it like this:

```
Delete t1 
FROM dbo.inventory t1
JOIN csv t2 ON t1.Year = t2.Year and t1.Month = t2.Month
```

I don't know how to do it in a Python script so I avoid loading my CSV file as a staging table into the datawarehouse, but just delete existing rows matching `Year` and `Month` and then loading them.

I have used the following in another setup:

```
delete_date = sales.Date.max()
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(f"""delete from sales where Date = '{delete_date}'""")
connection.close()
```

But this doesn't work here as the input for what should be deleted is a dataframe, which in theory could contain multiple year and months if it a correction to earlier loaded figures.

Answer (score 7):

Pandas doesn't support deletion of SQL rows based on specific conditions. You have to use SQLAlchemy for that:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://...')
meta = sa.MetaData()

# Map the Inventory table in your database to a SQLAlchemy object
inventory = sa.Table('Inventory', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

# Build the WHERE clause of your DELETE statement from rows in the dataframe.
# Equivalence in SQL:
#   WHERE (Year = <Year from row 1 of df> AND Month = <Month from row 1 of df>)
#      OR (Year = <Year from row 2 of df> AND Month = <Month from row 2 of df>)
#      ...
cond = df.apply(lambda row: sa.and_(inventory.c['Year'] == row['Year'], inventory.c['Month'] == row['Month']), axis=1)
cond = sa.or_(*cond)

# Define and execute the DELETE
delete = inventory.delete().where(cond)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(delete)

# Now you can insert the new data
df.to_sql('Inventory', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Comment: how would I do this if I only have one condition?  Would you still use 'sa.and'?  Would you still use 'cond = sa.or_(*cond)'?

Comment: What is your condition, in SQL?

Comment: where df.column.value = Inventory.column.value.  It's a more simple question than the one asked, but I can't find the right documentation on it.

Comment: basically if a column value in my dataframe is already in sql I need to replace the row with the row from my dataframe.

Comment: Try `cond = inventory.c['col_name'].in_(df['col_name'])`

Comment: I am still having trouble with this.  Please see the link to my question here if you can help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58018877/delete-sql-table-row-where-column-value-matches-pandas-dataframe-column-value

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it like this:

```
Inventory['Posting_date'] = pd.to_datetime(Inventory.Year.astype('str')+Inventory.Posting_period.astype('str'), format="%Y%m") + MonthEnd(1)

#Delete periods already existing in the database in order to avoid duplicates when reloading etc.
delete_date_inv = Inventory.Posting_date.drop_duplicates()
delete_date_inv = delete_date_inv.astype('str')
delete_date_inv = delete_date_inv.to_list()

#Apply the deletion of the destination
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(f"""delete from Inventory where Posting_date in ({str(delete_date_inv)[1:-1]})""")
connection.close()

#Load to the database
Inventory.to_sql('Inventory', schema = 'dbo', con=engine, if_exists='append', index = False, chunksize = 10000)
```

I am not sure if the above is more efficient that the other answers, but it works :-)

Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two good options.

1) working in Pandas. Query the existing table with Pandas.read_sql_table(), import the csv file as a second DataFrame and merge-update the old with the new. Then insert the updated DataFrame, for example using df.to_sql(..., if exists='update').

2) use sqlalchemy and work in the database, particularly if you want to preserve the schema or other conditions.

Below a brief and general example based on these two solutions. Others are more specific solution are likely possible, but these are two starting points.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as sa_dec
import sqlalchemy.orm as sa_orm
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import update
from sqlalchemy import and_

#con = sqlite3.connect('hyp.db')
#cur = con.cursor()

# general pandas solution
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3], 'month': [4, 5, 6], 'value': [2, 2, 2]})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 5, 3], 'month': [4, 9, 9], 'value': [1, 5, 10]})
c = pd.merge(t1, t2, how='outer', on=['year', 'month'], suffixes=['', '_t2'])
c.loc[c['value_t2'].notnull(), 'value'] = c.loc[c['value_t2'].notnull(), 'value_t2']
c = c.drop('value_t2', axis=1)
print(c)

# pandas using update
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 2, 3], 'month': [4, 5, 6], 'value': [2, 2, 2]})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1, 5, 3], 'month': [4, 9, 9], 'value': [1, 5, 10]})
c = pd.merge(t1, t2, how='outer', on=['year', 'month'], suffixes=['', '_t2'])
c['value'].update(c['value_t2'])
c = c.drop('value_t2', axis=1)
print(c)

# the c.to_sql(...)

##### sqlalchemy

Name = 'try.db'
Type = 'sqlite'
Url = sa.engine.url.URL(Type, database=Name)
Engine = sa.engine.create_engine(Url)
Base = sa_dec.declarative_base()
Session = sa_orm.sessionmaker(bind=Engine)

class Info(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Inventory'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    __table_args__ = (sa.UniqueConstraint('Year', 'Month'),)
    Year = sa.Column(sa.String(250))
    Month = sa.Column(sa.String(250))
    Value = sa.Column(sa.Float)

Base.metadata.create_all(Engine)

# change values of year and month to test
t = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [1, 2, 5], 'Month': ['Jun', 'July', 'Dec'], 'Value': [3, 3, 3]})


# this isn't very efficient but it is here to give you a comprehensive example
# where you have good control on what is happening
for i, r in t.iterrows():
    newdata = Info()
    for col, val in r.items():
        setattr(newdata, col, val)
    con = Engine.connect()
    session = Session()  # open sqlalchemy-sqlite session
    session.add(newdata)  # add Info instance to session to insert
    try:
        session.flush()  # test insert, to see if there is any error
    except sa.exc.IntegrityError:  # here catch unique constraint error if already in db
        print('already in')
        session.rollback()  # rollback to remove the blocked instance
        stmt = update(Info).where(and_(Info.Year == r['Year'], Info.Year == r['Month'])).values(Value=r['Value'])
        con.execute(stmt)
    else:
        session.commit()  # commit changes to db
    finally:
        session.close()  # close session to keep clean, it will be open in case of new data
        con.close()
```

I tested the two solutions, they seem to work but further tests are needed.