# Delete SQL Table Row Where Column Value Matches Pandas Dataframe Column Value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to delete rows in a SQL table that have a matching column value in my pandas dataframe.  This is the code I have so far.  It only works on some of the data for some reason.  I keep getting the error listed below.  What is the best way to do this?

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import update
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import or_
from sqlalchemy import and_

    engine = create_engine(cnxn_str)
    meta = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
    # Map the Inventory table in your database to a SQLAlchemy object
    inventory = sqlalchemy.Table(table_name, meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
    #make the condition
    cond = inventory.c['column_name'].in_(df['column_name'])
    # Define and execute the DELETE
    delete = inventory.delete().where(cond)
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(delete)

DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0) (SQLExecDirectW)') [SQL: 'DELETE FROM [table_name] WHERE [table_name].[column_name] IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
```

Comment: Stab in the dark, are there more than 1000 items in `df['column_name']`?

Comment: Yes!  Good question.  There are WAY more than 1000 rows.  Like 60,000.

Comment: The few SQL dialects I have used will not accept more than 1000 items in `IN`. However, I'm not sure exactly on the best way to fix that tbh

Comment: hmmmm... ok.  That must be it because it works on a small amount of the data but not the data as a whole.  How do you normally work your way around this?

Comment: As I said (edited to be fair), I don't know the best way. You could perhaps batch your DF in 1000 row chunks and do it that way, but I've never linked Pandas directly to SQL so it's all a hypothetical in my head and I could be leading you down the wrong path. But I do know that such a restriction exists on IN

Comment: For 60K rows, I can tell you what I would do. Just pull the lot and do the filtering in Pandas. You wouldn't have the same restriction there and it's not huge memory. But I would actually like to know the elegant way to do it, so I've starred and upvoted; hopefully someone answers in SQL terms :)

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old. Nevertheless, I will share my solution so it might help others.

I had a similar problem and ended up creating the follow function:

```
def execute_query(query: str, is_fw=False, conexion_ar=con_db_AR, conexion_fw="con_db_FW"):
"""

Parameters:
    query(str): Text with the query
    conexion_ar: Conexion to Redshift
    conexion_fw: Conexion to the framework
"""
if is_fw:
    conexion = conexion_fw
else:
    conexion = conexion_ar

conexion.execute(f"{query}; commit;")
```

Hope it helps ;D