# SQL Alchemy dynamically compare subset of columns to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I would like to compare rows of a SQL Server table to rows of a Pandas DataFrame. I'm comparing only certain columns (those that make up the primary key of the table.) Therefore I don't know how many columns to compare in advance. I want to modify the following to handle a composite primary key (fed in as a list of strings.) Currently this can only handle comparing one column and could be modified to handle multiple if they are known beforehand but I would like this to work dynamically.

```
# Build the WHERE clause of your DELETE statement from rows in the dataframe.
cond = df_update_partial.apply(lambda row: sa.and_(detail_table.c[key_col] == row[key_col]), axis=1) 
     # trying to fix the above, right now it is set up to handle a single string column name
cond = sa.or_(*cond)

# Define and execute the DELETE
delete = detail_table.delete().where(cond)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(delete)
```

Therefore the line in question above might need to look like:

```
cond = df_update_partial.apply(lambda row: sa.and_(detail_table.c[key_col[0]] == row[key_col[0]], detail_table.c[key_col[1]] == row[key_col[1]], detail_table.c[key_col[2]] == row[key_col[2]]), axis=1) 
     # above is for a primary key made up of 3 columns. key_col is a list of these columns names.
```

But if I don't know the length of this list beforehand I can't set it up this way.

Code originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57761954/delete-rows-from-sql-server-bases-on-content-in-dataframe).

Answer (score 0):

Python has a thing for lists called lexographic comparison

```py
row_one = ...
row_two = ...

list(row_one) == list(row_two)
# true if equally long AND all elements are the same
```

You should be able to use this

Comment: I'm not trying to compare two lists. I'm trying to create a conjunction of expressions using items in a list.